# MySQL distinct field count based on customer

Tags: mysql

I have the below MySQL table,

```
id   customer  Field_Name
1   C1  A
2   C1  B
3   C1  C
4   C1  D
5   C2  A
6   C2  D
7   C2  E
9   C3  B
10  C3  F
```

Customer "C1" has most number of fields (4) - A,B,C,D, 
"C2" has 3 fields - A,D,E and 
"C3" has 2 fields - B,F

Since customer "C1" has more fields, it should be taken first for comparing the customers

"C2" has A and D - "C1" has these two fields already and E is the only unique in "C2"

"C3" has B - "C1" has this field and F is only unique.

Similarly, it goes on...

I need to select distinct fields based on customers but based on customer with more number of fields.

Expected Result:

```
id   customer  Field_Name
1   C1  A
2   C1  B
3   C1  C
4   C1  D
7   C2  E
10  C3  F
```

Comment: *"Customer "C1" has most number of fields (4) - A,B,C,D, "C2" has 3 fields - A,D,E and "C3" has 2 fields - B,F"*   .... i assume you meant records/rows/tuples there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then the problem is fairly tractable:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer) cnt
    FROM customers
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Field_Name ORDER BY cnt DESC) rn
    FROM cte1
)

SELECT id, customer, Field_Name
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1;
```

### Demo

In earlier versions of MySQL, it should be possible to achieve the same logic, but in general simulating `ROW_NUMBER` can be a pain.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Then it is on the OP to give us extra logic which can resolve ties in all cases.  Specifically, we would need to add more columns to the `ORDER BY` clause of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Removed mine comments, when looking better in the example data and expected results i noticed mine comments about ties where a bit unnecessary

Comment: @Raymond You blow steam at everyone, it's quite entertaining actually.  I don't mind it `:-)`

Comment: not sure if i should take that comment positive or negative ...most of the times i see bears on the road (possible problems which can happen) everywhere..

Comment: I don't know who should more afraid...the bear, or we

Answer (score 0):

Without window functions, for earlier versions of MySql, you can use NOT EXISTS:

```
select * from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename tt
  where tt.customer <> t.customer and tt.field_name = t.field_name and 
    (select count(*) from tablename where customer = tt.customer) > 
    (select count(*) from tablename where customer = t.customer)
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9QZdjFTGM2Yq8g9S6NiMk/0).
Results:

```
| id  | customer | field_name |
| --- | -------- | ---------- |
| 1   | C1       | A          |
| 2   | C1       | B          |
| 3   | C1       | C          |
| 4   | C1       | D          |
| 7   | C2       | E          |
| 10  | C3       | F          |
```